# POI to open XLTX to create XLSX

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI Java methods to create Excel from an IBM iSeries (AS400); using RPG to call Java via Prototyping... from Scott Klement's.

I have a process that creates XLS Files using XLT Templates; but I am having a problem trying to use XLTX to create XLSX excels...  If use XLSX as a Template All works fine,.....  but NO Cell Formatting is saved.

There is no XSSFWorkbook Workbook Constructor that would translate as follow:

```
public HSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream s,
            boolean preserveNodes)
             throws java.io.IOException
```

I am trying to find an example that I could use to translate into my process.

Comment: What's wrong with http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html ? Where's your XLSX-specific code?

Comment: If you get this working on the PC I can help you export a runnable jar to the as400 or call from RPG into Jar on the 400.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, got side tracked by other projects,

Comment: I not sure I could post my code;  I am using a Non-Java programming language to execute the Java Methods in POI...  version 3.6.

Comment: Danny, thanks for the offer,  I know how to call, execute the prototyping calls from RPG to Java Jars,  just having problems with XLTX to XLSX,

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved your case? Have you used

•   dom4j-1.6.1.jar from DOM4J (version 1.6.1 or higher)

•   jsr173_1.0_api.jar from XmlBeans 2.5.0 (or higher)

•   xbean.jar from XmlBeans 2.5.0 (or higher)

These jar files are required additionally, as Scott says. 
I will be testing it next days, and your case would be interesting for us.